# How to know when will the instance of Node be an Element?

Tags: java, jsoup

The [documentation](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/helper/W3CDom.W3CBuilder.html#head(org.jsoup.nodes.Node,int)) of Jsoup for Nodevisitor head says

> If it's instanceOf Element, you may cast it to an Element and access those methods.

The doc specifies what we can do when the instance of Node is Element. My question is when is the instance of the Node passed into argument of head function is Element? How is that decided?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  The documentation says that you can use `if( node instanceOf Element )` to test the type of the `Node`.  Whether something is an Element or something else is defined by the [specification](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp).  Could you elaborate what difficulty you are having?

Comment: @markspace, Yeah, I get that I can use something like `if ( node isInstanceOf Element) thenDoSomething()`, my question is in which scenarios / cases will node passed in the argument of head function be of instance Element or something else?

Answer (score 0):

@VivekShah please make your problem statement more specific, provide some more error/exception. If i understood your question properly which is, "in which scenarios/cases will Node passed in the argument of head function be of instance Element". Your can find answer to your question at below link, please go through it.
https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/org.w3c.dom.Node

Also putting this information as it is relevant to this question, may be helpful to someone,

if(node instanceof Element) to test the type of the Node thenDoSomething();

Missing the above check make cause following Excpetion like this,

Excpetion :: class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredTextImpl cannot be cast to class org.w3c.dom.Element (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredTextImpl and org.w3c.dom.Element are in module java.xml of loader 'bootstrap')